# How can I add a background image to this page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I found, what seems to be, a fantastic open-source Node.JS login system on GitHub. It is located [here](https://github.com/braitsch/node-login). I set it up on my website (cend.io). Everything is cool.

Now, what I would like to do, is add a stretched out, responsive background image to the main page. Something like [this](http://webthemez.com/demo/coming-soon-responsive-web-template-trendset/).

What would be the most efficient method of doing this, given the complexities of the Node.JS login system?

Thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: No need to use jQuery, just use CSS like you would anywhere else. The current background gradient is being applied to the `body` tag in the `style.css` file.

Comment: Nice. Was wondering if that could be done. What's the significance of the style.styl file? It looks like a CSS file without as much syntax. Does this need to be adjusted as well?

Comment: You should only make the change in the styl file, it is the pre-processed CSS file so each time you compile it, the style.css file will be overwritten with whatever is in the stylus file

Comment: Excellent - thank you very much for your help. I'm going to give this a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this to CSS :

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; // change to your own image
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This will add a full page background image to the `html` element.

Comment: This is working for me. I had to stick the code in the body tag, rather than html.

Comment: @cbclark - Yes, `body` will work too. Could you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need jQuery, setting the background image can be done with pure JavaScript like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image.png')";
```

Comment: Cool, this seems really simple. Part of my confusion stems from the fact that there's no "index.html" file to work with. It's all .jade files in the server folder. Would this solution still work / would the code change?

Comment: Why use JavaScript at all when you can use plain CSS?

Comment: @Apad1 He asked how to use jQuery to do it so i gave an answer in JavaScript; but your right you could do it in CSS and you could use jQuery to set the CSS...

Comment: Yep, sorry, my question was directed at the OP not you, this is definitely how it would be done with JavaScript.

Comment: @cbclark - See my answer below. Definitely the best way to do this. Don't use JavaScript for styling. That's what CSS is for.

Comment: Thank you @aphextwix! I'm going to try adding your code to the .styl file and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @APAD1 You're right. I'm quickly learning that the CSS approach is probably much, much easier. I'm not sure why the "Coming Soon" template I looked at used the more complicated approach... thank you for your help!